# GraphQL column alias name

Tags: graphql, label, alias, apollo-client

Is it possible to use an alias name on a graphql query such as SQL (see below)

```
select productCode as 'ID' from product
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering much googling... here it is.

```
 query { 
   product { 
     ID : productCode 
   } 
 }
```